# Dynamically append multiple options selected into one select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the options selected from one select element into another. I'm guessing it'll be something like this.

```
 var selected = $("#selectWithOptions").append("<option'>" + 
 options[selectedIndex].value + "</option>");
```

This does not work.

Comment: Why can't you just use a loop?

Comment: You have a rogue apostrophe `( ' )` after the first occurrence of `option`. Might that be the issue?

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Comment: You have to provide more of your code for us to understand what is going on. In your code you are referencing DOM objects and variables that are a black box for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is pretty straight-forward and you can follow the inline comments in the JS function:

```js
// Fire this function when a dropdown item is selected
$('#dd1').change(function() {
  // Grab the text of the selected item
  var selectedOption = $('#dd1 :selected').text();
  // If it is not already in the second dropdown list, then append it
  if( $('#dd2 option').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == selectedOption; }).length <= 0 ) {
      $('#dd2').append('<option>'+selectedOption);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Dropdown 1: 
  <select id="dd1">
    <option selected disabled>Select option</option>  
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>baz</option>
    <option>xiyar</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>Dropdown 2:
  <select id="dd2">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you undo tho? updating the value rather if the user change his mind and pick something else?

Comment: Edited to prevent adding the same option more than once if selected again.

Comment: Regarding code-only answers, it is hard to see what was changed or proposed as a fix. Would you be able to add an introductory paragraph, Aydin?

Comment: Updated, @halfer

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript(and jQuery), everything is an object. Get the selected option elements using the jquery `:selected` selector and then append them to the second `select` element.

I'm using `clone()` but if you don't want to copy, rather you want to move the elements from one `select` to the other, then get rid of `clone()` and that same object will be moved to the other `select` element.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(e){
 var opt = $('#first option:selected').clone();
  $('#second').append(opt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first">
  <option value="hello">Hello</option>
  <option value="world">World</option>
</select>
<select id="second">

</select>
<button>
Copy
</button>
```